# drop down menu disappear when I trying to select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make navigation bar for my website by using HTML, CSS,and jQuery but the problem I am getting is when I hover on an element which has dropdown list It will get disappear before my selection. Here is my complete code.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z8pwoqqk/)

**HTML**

```
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>``
            <li><a href="#">About</a>
                <ul>

                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tell</a></li>   
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="selected">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tell</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tell</a></li>   
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
                </ul>``
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.selected{
background:#CCC;
}
#menu{
width:500px;
height:70px;
margin:40px auto;
border:1px solid black;
border-radius:5px;
}
#menu ul{
list-style:none;
position:relative;
}
#menu ul li{
float:left;
position:relative;
width:100px;
text-align:center;
}
#menu ul li a{
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
background:black;
color:white;
padding:10px 30px;
line-height:30px;
}

#menu ul li ul{
display:none;
visibility:hidden;
opacity:0;
position:absolute;  
top:50px;
left:0px;
padding:0;
width:150px;    
}
#menu ul li a:hover, #menu ul li .selected{
background:gray;
    color:white;
}


#menu ul li ul li{
    list-style:none;
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
    width:150px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

    $("#menu ul li a").click(function(e){

        $("#menu ul li a").removeClass("selected");
        }).click (function(){

            $(this).addClass("selected");
            });


        $("#menu ul li a").mouseenter(function(){
            $("#menu ul li ul").slideToggle("fast");

            });     

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are tying the slideToggle after your click. If you structure your code a bit better, you would notice this right away. Also, you are defining your list of a's to often. So first, lets clean up your Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    // we only need one click event!
    $("#menu ul li a").click(function(event){
        // We only want to selected the a.selected and remove there, its slightly faster!
        $("#menu ul li a.selected").removeClass("selected");
        // We can immediately add the class to this element
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

I have also removed your `slideToggle`, for a good reason. We want to do this with css!

```
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.selected{
    background:#CCC;
}
#menu{
    width:500px;
    height:70px;
    margin:40px auto;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:5px;
}
#menu ul{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
}
#menu ul li{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
}

#menu ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    padding:10px 30px;
    line-height:30px;
}

#menu ul li ul{
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;  
    top:50px;
    left:0px;
    padding:0;
    width:150px;    
}
#menu ul li a:hover, 
#menu ul li .selected{
    background:gray;
    color:white;
}

/* Here is some magic. We hide the overflow and give it no height, so it appears hidden. */
#menu ul li ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 500ms;
}

#menu ul li ul li {
    list-style:none;
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
}

/* We add a state for when we hover on the ul itself, and give that a bigger max-height. */
#menu ul li:hover ul
#menu ul li ul:hover {
    visibility:visible;
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
    width:150px;
    /* And this will make it work! */
    max-height: 500px;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
// we only need one click event!
$("#menu ul li a").click(function(event){
    // We only want to selected the a.selected and remove there, its slightly faster!
    $("#menu ul li a.selected").removeClass("selected");
    // We can immediately add the class to this element
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
  
});
```

```css
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.selected{
    background:#CCC;
}
#menu{
    width:500px;
    height:70px;
    margin:40px auto;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:5px;
}
#menu ul{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
}
#menu ul li{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
}

#menu ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    padding:10px 30px;
    line-height:30px;
}

#menu ul li ul{
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;  
    top:50px;
    left:0px;
    padding:0;
    width:150px;    
}
#menu ul li a:hover, 
#menu ul li .selected{
    background:gray;
    color:white;
}

/* Here is some magic. We hide the overflow and give it no height, so it appears hidden. */
#menu ul li ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    display:block;
    max-height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 500ms;
    transition: max-height 500ms;
}

#menu ul li ul li {
    list-style:none;
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
}

/* We add a state for when we hover on the ul itself, and give that a bigger max-height. */
#menu ul li:hover ul,
#menu ul li ul:hover {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    width:150px;
    /* And this will make it work! */
    max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>``
            <li><a href="#">About</a>
                <ul>

                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tell</a></li>   
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="selected">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tell</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tell</a></li>   
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
                </ul>``
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a z-index in your styling so that your menu bar shows up on top of all of your other elements.  I think your page is covering your dropdown.  Add

```
z-index: 99;
```

to your menu class or on of the dropdown elements.